# Exibir parcelas em página de produto prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

Bom dia, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar me indicando como faço para exibir o preço e quantidade de parcelas em uma página de detalhe de produto (product.tpl) no prestashop. Exemplo: **10 x de R$ 10,00**. Se alguém souber agradeço desde já.

Vinícius Lima

Comment: você quer desenvolver um addon próprio ou pode ser um existente? Normalmente são addons pagos.

Comment: Eu quero desenvolver um próprio, mas não sei se isso caracterizaria um addon ou algo que alguém compraria pois só quero puxar esta informação de parcelas e valor de cada uma do banco e exibir no front. Poderia retornar pro front até um array mesmo fora daquele objeto $product.

Comment: Há dois meios. Um meio mais simples é criar um override no módulo que exibe detalhe do produto no front. Outro meio é criar um módulo no qual é adicionado um hook em ProductDetails (front). Opinião pessoal, um hook é melhor pois um override não tem bem essa finalidade, é mais para corrigir uma funcionalidade padrão. No seu caso é implementar uma nova funcionalidade, por isso recomendo criar um módulo.

Comment: Bom na verdade eu já imaginava isso, minha dúvida principal é se existe algum lugar pelo qual eu posso puxar essa informação por exemplo um Product::getParcels(), ou Product::getAllData que me retorna-se do banco as parcelas e preço das mesmas pois não sei em qual tabela ficam guardadas. Meu problema é tirar essa informação do banco, a implementação no tema eu consigo fazer de boa desde que consiga tirar as informações do banco através de algum método de alguma classe ou no mínimo sabendo a tabela onde estão salvas.

Comment: certo, acho que eu consigo obter a informação. quando encontrar publicarei aqui.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado Daniel. Também estarei buscando. Valeu pela ajuda!